# How to set color to text in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I just want to change color of text using style in tag

How can I do that?

```
<div id="root"></div><br>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script><br>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><br>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script><br>

<script type="text/babel">
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');<br>
const element = <h1>Hello world</h1><br>

ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement);<br>
</script>
```

Comment: you mean inline css? like: `<h1 style="color: red;">Hello world</h1>`

Comment: @AsharDweedar yes, but is this works in react js?

Answer (score 38):

You can use inline-style like:

```
const element = <h1 style={{ color: 'red' }}>Hello world</h1>
```

or

```
const hStyle = { color: 'red' };
const element = <h1 style={ hStyle }>Hello world</h1>
```

**For more info:**

- [Inline Styles](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

**Demo:**

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const element = <h1 style={{ color: 'red' }}>Hello world</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: second one is worked! Thanks. But why first one is not working?

Comment: I missed one additional bracket. It should also work now.

Answer (score 7):

**style tag** in index.html

```
<style>
  .textColor{
     color : 'red'
  }
<style>
```

Use : `<h1 className="textColor">text colors</h1>`

**Inline**:

```
<h1 style={{ color: 'red' }}>inline styling</h1>
```

Using **Style Object**

```
const styles= {
    color: 'red',
};
<h1 style={styles}>Style obje</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use external css file and then import it in your code

**You can also use Inline CSS**

```
<NavLin / to="/home" activeStyle={{ color:'green', fontWeight: 'bold'}}> Home </NavLin>
```

*Object of style can be populated here*

```
activeStyle={{ color:'green', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
```

Comment: when you answer try to format code. Here is guideline
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below :

```
<h1 style={{color: 'red'}}>Hello world</h1>
```

React treats style attribute as an object. So we have to provide double quotes "{{ }}" and inside that is our css code.
Also the notation should be `camel-case`.
e.g. `{{backgroundColor: 'red'}}`

Answer (score 1):

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p style={{fontSize: '2rem'}}>
        Hi {' '}
        <span style={{color: 'white', backgroundColor: 'green'}}>Hello</span>{' '}
        text
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```